# How to select only the rows of provided table id's

Tags: mysql, sql

If i have a table named products and its structure looked like this

```
id
product
price
```

How can I select only the rows whose id's are 3,6,10,13,15 ?
These values are dynamic though but will be provided.
Instead of doing select statement `where id = '3' and id='6'` and so on is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I am very sure you mean instead of `where id='3' or id='6'` etc, i.e. **or** not **and**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming PHP...

```
$ids = array(3, 6, 10, 13, 15);

$query = 'SELECT * 
            FROM `table` 
           WHERE `id`
                  IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
select * from table where id in (3,6,10,13,15);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(3,6,10,13,15)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where id in(3,6,10,13,15)
```

edit:  looks like I was 15 seconds slow!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN ( 3,6,10,13,15 )
```